# Domain of the axes does not exactly defines how chart is rendered

Tags: altair

While specifying domain starting at zero:

```
alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1000))
```

I still obtain a plot with negative values on the X axis:
[image]

I don't understand why is it behaving like this? And how to force it starting always exactly at the value, provided in the domain?

Code for plotting:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'foo': {0: 250,
  1: 260,
  2: 270,
  3: 280,
 },
 'cnt': {0: 6306,
  1: 5761,
  2: 5286,
  3: 4785,
 }})


alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X(
            'foo',
            scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1000))
        ),
        alt.Y("cnt")
```

Lib version:
altair                            3.2.0

Comment: Your code has undefined variables. Please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your code appears to have uncovered a bug in Vega-Lite; I've filed an issue at [vega/vega-lite#5295](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5295)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bar marks, Vega-Lite automatically adds a padding to domains (this is not the case for other mark types). The fact that it does this even when the user explicitly specifies the domain is a bug; see [vega/vega-lite#5295](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5295).

As a workaround until this bug is fixed, you can turn this behavior offby setting `padding=0`:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [250, 260, 270, 280],
    'cnt': [6306, 5761, 5286, 4785]
})


alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X(
        'foo',
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 1000), padding=0)
    ),
    alt.Y("cnt")
)
```

[image]